# Programming a little file to change between headset and monitor speakers?

Tags: windows-7, audio, batch, code

I think there is a way to write a little file in Batch, I believe to change the default sound output system. What's the language that's written in and how can I write it (I am running Windows 7)? Thanks.

EDIT:
I know how to change it normally btw... I just want a faster way to execute it so I don't have to go to my sound properties.

Comment: This should be possible via PowerShell. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to use a hotkey.

Hope this helps. [How to change the default audio device with a hotkey](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/06/16/windows-7-tip-how-to-change-the-default-audio-device-with-a-hot).